# Android - Layout with images

Tags: android, image, layout

I've been working on this for few days but I couldn't get the layout I need.
I would like to have a layout similar to the image below.
Can anyone guide me with this ? What kind of layout and view should I use ?

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: its very simple and easy to produce by using RelativeLayout

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ive added some code generated by drawing what you want in the layout editor in eclipse.

Looks like this

[image: Layouts]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.81" >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.00"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView02"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.00"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `LinearLayout`. In the first row you can add another two `LinearLayouts` with horizontal orientation. So: `LinearLayout` container (orientation horizontal). In the first row add two `LinearLayouts` with vertical orientation. First coloumn image1, second column `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation (every row image 2,3,4). Return to container, on the second row add image 5 :)

Comment: android layout is a little bit awful.. so if you use always linear layout you could simplify your life :)

Answer (score 0):

Use TableLayout for your views.

Answer (score 0):

i am giving only prototype of layout may be it will help you
look at that

```
<linearLayout main android;orientation="vertical">
<linearlayout "sub1" android;orientation="horizontal">
<linearlayout android:layout_wight="1" "take first lesthand side image in it" >
<linearlayout android:layout_wight="1" "sub2" android:orientation="vertical" >
"take three linearlayout and set three images in that take a weight as 1 for all three linearlayout "
<close sub2 linear layout>
<close sub1 linear layout>
```

take another linear layout and set last bottom image in it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!-- Root layout -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/container"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Layout for img1,2,3,4 -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/img1234
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- ImageView for img1 -->
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/img234"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:orientation="vertical">
            <!-- ImageView for img2 -->
            <!-- ImageView for img3 -->
            <!-- ImageView for img4 -->           
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- Here should be ImageView for img5. Either use weight (to ensure proportions)
         or set an absolute height in dp -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Excuse me for possible typos.